# How do I set ion-sides-menus title to its child ion-view title?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm currently using Ionic version 1.2.4.

I have a parent view `app` which is an `ion-side-menus` directive. Currently, the `ion-side-menu-content`->`ion-nav-bar` has a title but its sub-views aren't changing the `ion-nav-bar` title.

Here's the `app` source:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable has-header" align-title="center">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>

        <h1 class="title">
          Default Title
        </h1>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/view1">
          View 1
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/view2">
          View 2
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

And the `app` state is setup like:

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
  url: '',
  abstract: true,
  template: '<app></app>'
});
```

The sub-view is properly being loaded into `ion-nav-view`, but it's `view-title` isn't updating the `ion-nav-bar` title.

Here's the source for `view1`:

```
<ion-view view-title="View 1">
  <ion-content>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And the `view1` state is setup like:

```
$stateProvider.state('app.view1', {
  url: '/view1'
});
```

I'm using angular `component` for the `controller` and `templateUrl` attributes.

How do I get the sub-view to update its parent view `ion-nav-bar` title when using `ion-side-menus`?

Comment: How are your ui-router states set up?

Comment: @ankur: I've updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of tinkering this has been solved...

To make this work I modified the `app` template source where the `ion-nav-view` was and added the name attribute:
`<ion-nav-view name="appContent"></ion-nav-view>`

And in the child views I modified the `state` to look like:

```
$stateProvider.state('app.view1', {
  url: '/view1',
  views: {
    'appContent': {
      templateUrl: `path/to/view1.html`
    }
  }
});
```

Inside the `view1` template source I added the `ion-nav-title` directive like so:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-nav-title>View 1</ion-nav-title>
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <p>View 1</p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Now child views `ion-nav-title` change the nav bar title respectively.